# java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException when running druid sample app

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, druid

I am trying out druid.io with zookeeper 34.6 on fedora 20 x64. U am following tut [here](
http://druid.io/docs/latest/Tutorial:-A-First-Look-at-Druid.html)

After huge effort I am able to run zookeeper. Now when I run the server of sample druid app
It gives me below error. Notice that it says  `Inventory initialized`

```
2015-06-21T17:14:03,472 INFO [ServerInventoryView-0] io.druid.client.BatchServerInventoryView - Inventory Initialized
2015-06-21T17:14:03,472 ERROR [main] io.druid.cli.CliBroker - Error when starting up.  Failing.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
at com.metamx.common.lifecycle.Lifecycle$AnnotationBasedHandler.start(Lifecycle.java:331) ~[java-util-0.27.0.jar:?]
    at com.metamx.common.lifecycle.Lifecycle.start(Lifecycle.java:250) ~[java-util-0.27.0.jar:?]
    at io.druid.guice.LifecycleModule$2.start(LifecycleModule.java:136) ~[druid-api-0.3.8.jar:0.7.3]
    at io.druid.cli.GuiceRunnable.initLifecycle(GuiceRunnable.java:71) [druid-services-0.7.3.jar:0.7.3]
    at io.druid.cli.ServerRunnable.run(ServerRunnable.java:38) [druid-services-0.7.3.jar:0.7.3]
    at io.druid.cli.Main.main(Main.java:88) [druid-services-0.7.3.jar:0.7.3]
Caused by: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:127) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:640) ~[?:1.7.0_45]
    at com.ircclouds.irc.api.comms.SocketChannelConnection.open(SocketChannelConnection.java:24) ~[irc-api-1.0-0011.jar:?]
at com.ircclouds.irc.api.AbstractIRCSession.open(AbstractIRCSession.java:104) ~[irc-api-1.0-0011.jar:?]
    at com.ircclouds.irc.api.IRCApiImpl.connect(IRCApiImpl.java:99) ~[irc-api-1.0-0011.jar:?]
    at io.druid.segment.realtime.firehose.IrcFirehoseFactory.connect(IrcFirehoseFactory.java:116) ~[druid-server-0.7.3.jar:0.7.3]
at io.druid.segment.realtime.firehose.IrcFirehoseFactory.connect(IrcFirehoseFactory.java:59) ~[druid-server-0.7.3.jar:0.7.3]
    at io.druid.segment.realtime.FireDepartment.connect(FireDepartment.java:97) ~[druid-server-0.7.3.jar:0.7.3]
    at io.druid.segment.realtime.RealtimeManager$FireChief.init(RealtimeManager.java:207) ~[druid-server-0.7.3.jar:0.7.3]
    at io.druid.segment.realtime.RealtimeManager.start(RealtimeManager.java:109) ~[druid-server-0.7.3.jar:0.7.3]
    ... 10 more
```

So which address it is failing to resolve? I am new to both druid and zookeeper so must be missing some architectural understanding.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can occur with the wikipedia firehose if you are behind a corporate firewall. If you try at home, do you see the same problem? FWIW, you will get a faster response by posting questions here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/druid-user

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.